# from join table follow a foreign key to get attribute

Tags: django

I have a join table:

```
class ReviewTag(models.Model):

    review = models.ForeignKey(Review)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

I do the following to get a list of ReviewTag objects:

```
review.reviewtag_set.all()
```

If Tag has an attribute called 'name'.  How do i create a list of names from the list of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[reviewtag.tag.name for reviewtag in review.reviewtag_set.all().select_related()]
```

or

```
[tag.name for tag in Tag.objects.filter(reviewtag__review=review)]
```

or

```
Tag.objects.filter(reviewtag__review=review).values_list('name', flat=True)
```

---

The development version of django has support for `values` across JOINs
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values

Which would let you do

```
review.reviewtag_set.all().values('tag__name')
```

Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To your review class you could add a M2M with a through attr.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

```
 class Review(models.Model):
    ..
    tags = models.ManyToMany('yourapp.Tag', through='ReviewTag')


  review.tags.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Would then give you a lazy list of tag names associated with this review, I believe.